# how to fetch records based upon the order of rows of a column

Tags: sql, oracle

So I am having below table /colums

Table A

```
filedName  newValue   OldValue
name        a           b
email       x           y
contactNo   123         432
name        aa          bb
email       xx          yy
contactNo   1234        4324
```

I want the data based upon the name ,contact and email basis like the date should come like below

```
name --a 
contact -123
email-x
name ---aa
contact--1234
email--xx
```

This is basically the order of rows for the column field name.
Anyone please advice.

FYI:I had joined this table with few more table as well.

Comment: You seem to think that email x belongs to name a and  email xx belongs to name aa. What makes you think so? You know, data in a table has no inherent order, so you'd need some key (e.g. a person_id) to group rows that belong together. Is there such key you merely forgot to show us?

Comment: Is there a reason by the way you have decided for a key-value table? They are usually a pain to work with. Why don't you simply have a persons table with columns for name, email address and contact number?

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want, if error let me know, not on a pc

```
Select *
From
(
    Select filedvalue, newvalue, oldvalue, 
    row_number() over (partition by filedname order by newvalue) r ,
   Case filedvalue 
        When 'name' then 1 
        When 'Contactno' then 2 
        When 'Email' then 3 
        Else 9999
   End ordby
   From table 
) x
Order by r,ordby
```

Answer (score 0):

A sort of hackish way is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA
ORDER BY CASE CAST(filedName + '_' + newValue as varchar) 
             WHEN 'name_a' THEN 1
             WHEN 'contactNo_123' THEN 2
             WHEN 'email_x' THEN 3
             WHEN 'name_aa' THEN 4
             WHEN 'contactNo_1234' THEN 5
             WHEN 'email_xx' THEN 6
             ELSE 7
         END
```